# swimlane/ngx-datatable, How can I kick the cellClass function?

Tags: ngx-datatable

The `cellClass` function is not called when the component properties change.

How do I kick a `rowClass` or`cellClass`?

```
@Component({
  ...,
  template: `<ngx-datatable [rowClass]="rowClass"></ngx-datatable>`
})
class SomeComponent {
  someVariable = true;

  rowClass = (row) => {
    return {
      'some-class': (() => { return this.someVariable === row.someVariable })()
    };
  }
}
```

Related
https://github.com/swimlane/ngx-datatable/issues/774

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve it by changing `this.rows`.

https://swimlane.gitbook.io/ngx-datatable/cd

```
this.rows = [...this.rows];
```

If you are using a store, you need to cancel the immutable attribute.

Example

```
  @Input() set list(list: Record<string, unknown>[]) {
    if (list.length) {
      // If the search results are reflected in the table.
      // And 20 items are loaded at a time.
      if (list.length === 20) {
        this.rows = list.map((item) => ({ ...item }));
      // Load more items
      } else {
        const newRows = list.map((item) => ({ ...item })).slice(this.rows.length);
        this.rows = this.rows.concat(newRows);
      }
    }
  }
```